# Is it possible to split the optimization problem into multiple sub problem if the objective function and constraints are separable?

Tags: optimization, transformation

I am a post graduate electrical engineering student who is working with some optimization. Suddenly, I realize that my problem ${\left( P \right)}$ is quite separable in both objective function and constraint. Particularly, my problem has the form

$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\left( P \right)}&{\mathop {\min }\limits_{x,y,z} }&{{g_1}\left( x \right) + {g_2}\left( y \right) + {g_3}\left( z \right)}\\
{}&{s.t}&{{x_L} \le {f_1}\left( x \right) \le {x_U}}\\
{}&{}&{{y_L} \le {f_2}\left( y \right) \le {y_U}}\\
{}&{}&{{z_L} \le {f_3}\left( z \right) \le {z_U}}
\end{array}$

Here $x_L$,$y_L$ and $z_L$ are some numerical lower bound. Likewise $x_U$,$y_U$ and $z_U$ are some numerical upper bound.

Therefore, my question is that can I find the optimal decision variable $x,y,z$ of problem $(P)$ by solving these 3 separates univariate problem $P_1$, $P_2$ and $P_3$ ?

$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\left( {{P_1}} \right)}&{\mathop {\min }\limits_x }&{{g_1}\left( x \right)}\\
{}&{s.t}&{{x_L} \le {f_1}\left( x \right) \le {x_U}}
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\left( {{P_2}} \right)}&{\mathop {\min }\limits_y }&{{g_2}\left( y \right)}\\
{}&{s.t}&{{y_L} \le {f_2}\left( y \right) \le {y_U}}
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\left( {{P_3}} \right)}&{\mathop {\min }\limits_z }&{{g_3}\left( z \right)}\\
{}&{s.t}&{{z_L} \le {f_3}\left( z \right) \le {z_U}}
\end{array}$

Also, if the answer is 'yes' then what would be the rigorous explanation for this approach ?

Note that sometimes $f(.)$ and $g(.)$ are not differentiable.

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Comment: Yes you can solve these problems separately. You can show it rigorously several ways depending on what you know about $\min$ and the regularity of the functions involved. One way, if everything is differentiable, is to show the optimality conditions are coherent with the two different formulations.

Comment: I am an engineer so that I do not understand much about math concept such as regularity. Also in my application sometime $f(.)$ and $g(.)$ are not differentiable.

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh How about: Let $x^\ast$ be the solution to (P1),
$y^\ast$ be the solution to (P2), $z^\ast$ be the solution to (P3). 
We have $g_1(x) + g_2(y) + g_3(z) 
\ge g_1(x^\ast) + g_2(y^\ast) + g_3(z^\ast)$
whenever $(x, y, z)$ is feasible for (P).
In other words, $(x^\ast, y^\ast, z^\ast)$ is the solution to (P).